# How to share a website file with mongoDB database

Tags: database, mongodb

So my task is to write an assignment in nodejs and bootstrap with mongodb database.

My next task is to share this with the Assignee in a way so that he/ she can run the project in his/ her local environment.

I can transfer the codes in git and share but how to share the database as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can see MongoDB documentation for that
`mongodump -d <database_name> -o <directory_backup>`

`mongorestore -d <database_name> <directory_backup>`
 [video for mongoexport command](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Phe9B2HRVmc)

Comment: This looks promising. Thanks a lot. (y)

Answer (score 0):

You could use a database-as-a-service like [mlab](https://mlab.com) so that the database will be the same on both the machines.

Or if you don't like external database, you could also create a node.js script to init the database the first time the program is run.

Comment: Thanks, I will give it a try

Answer (score 0):

Use studio3T, choose your collection. Right click on the collection and export in your desired format. Same way your colleague will import from Studio3T.